# Помогите с устаревшим die(mysql_error() и mysql_num_rows() в php 7.1

Tags: php, sql

Сто лет не занимался кодом, подзабыл слегка + не знаю.
На 5.5 писал давно такой простой запрос для регистрации пользователя: когда в базе есть подобный пользователь, то выводит оповещение. На 7.1 это уже не раб. Помогите осуществить то же самое , только на 7.1 пхп

```
$query = ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'");
$sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
echo 'Пользователь с таким логином уже зарегестрирован!';
}
```

Коннекчу базу так : `$conn->`

Зарнее спасибо. Всем хорошего зрения и шустрых пальцев.

МОЖЕТ ПРИГОДИТСЯ :)
Недолго думая сварганил так:

```
    $allstr = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE login='$login'");
    $sql = $allstr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    $astr = ($sql[0]);


if ($astr > 0) {
echo 'Пользователь с таким логином уже зарегестрирован!';
}
```

Comment: "подзабыл слегка + не знаю." --- не знал, да ещё и забыл! Отлично!))

Comment: Для 7.1 нужно всё переписывать либо на mysqli либо PDO. В целом, достаточно добавить только `i` в конце. Но это будет просто работать лишь бы работало. По хорошему тут надо всё переписывать полностью. Используя подготовленные переменные и в целом не используя эти страшные `die()`

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select  .... где-то это было на русском. но не помню

Comment: Спасибо, погнал учить то что забыл + не знал то что, забыл)))